# memoir - \leftmark in footer ignored on oneside document

Tags: memoir, footer, single-sided

I have a document and created the footer style as follows.

```
\copypagestyle{normal}{plain} 
\makeevenfoot{normal}{\thepage}{}{\leftmark}
\makeoddfoot{normal}{\leftmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{normal}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{normal}{}{}{}
```

The code works fine when I set the `twosided` option in the document class. But when I switch to `oneside` the page numbers always show up on the right (that is good), but the \leftmark command seems to be ignored completely, the chapter name won't show up in the footer.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site please post a full minimal example instead of just a sniplet. This makes it a lot easier for others to help, especially when they do not need to add anything in order to test the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look in the `memoir` code. If `oneside` is active `\chapter` only write to `\rightmark`.

Here is how to make it write to both

```
\makeatletter
\addtopsmarks{normal}{}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{normal}
```

It adds the redefinition at the end of the psmarks for `normal`, thus overwriting the default for `chapter`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the info. Wouldn't it be also sufficent to just change leftmark to rightmark? `\makeoddfoot{normal}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}`

Comment: @Thommy, it would, but with my change this pagestyle can be used under both two side and one side with no further changes. I have wondered why chapter does not just write to both by default. Too late to change now